# Apache 1.3.37 not logging 404 errors

Tags: apache-http-server, http-status-code-404, error-logging

While attempting to diagnose another issue (which I asked about [over here](https://superuser.com/questions/373797/)), I discovered that the apache 1.3.37 installation on a machine I inherited doesn't log 404 errors to `error_log`.  I've scoured the config files for `CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` directives, but they're all just the standard 'set a path and (for CustomLog) combined format' type.

It does log other errors normally, such as 'Permission denied', but 404s are silently ignored.

What might be causing this and how can I get the 404s to appear (at least temporarily)?

Comment: Have you checked your access.log for the 404?

Comment: @Nifle: Yes, the request shows in access_log with a 404 status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the context of the [original issue](https://superuser.com/questions/373797/) was relevant here - the problem URL contained the sequence `%2F` (a URI-encoded forward slash).  In an attempt to protect security-oblivious CGI programmers from their own ignorance, apache immediately rejects (as 404 Not found) any requested URL which contains that sequence at a very early stage in the request-handling process, which apparently bypasses any writes to `error_log`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive is configured (also check .htaccess files) which excludes 404s.